# android is returning an error when making a call or sending a text message

Tags: android

android is returning an error when making a call or sending a text message 
it says "`internal processing. please retry to later`"
I know it sounds grammatically incorrect but that's exactly how the error is displayed when making a phone call.any ideas on what the error means OR how to fix the issue ?
everything else works, wifi connects to the internet, the signal is full bars, the name of the  phone network is there. any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you tried to send messages using code or issue faced in device ah?

Comment: Is this a programming question? If so, please show some relevant code. If not, your question should be posted on the http://android.stackexchange.com/ site instead.